# Basecamp 3 API : How to get comments created by the authorized user?

Tags: api, basecamp

I am in the process of integrating my webapp with Basecamp 2 (solved, see edit) and 3, and I want to get all of the comments for a todo item for the authorized user.

First I make a call to `https://launchpad.37signals.com/authorization.json` which returns json that includes the user's identity, something like `{"identity":{"id":99999999,  ..... }}`.

Then I make a call to the URL to get the comments for the item in question and go through them one by one matching the `identity.id` from above (99999999) with the `creator.id` for the comment.

The problem is, they don't match! I am working with one Basecamp2 project and one Basecamp3 project. When testing, using comments I wrote, Basecamp2 and Basecamp3 each have different values for `creator.id` (even though I wrote both comments!), and neither of them match the `identity.id` from `authorization.json`.

How do I link them to find which comments were made by the authorized user

Thanks

EDIT: I figured it out for Basecamp2 - I need [to get `/people.json`](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/people.md) which has a mapping from the `identity_id` of each user to the `id` for that user in that project. Still not sure how to do it for Basecamp3, which does not include `identity_id` in `people.json`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this for Basecamp2 is to get:

`https://basecamp.com/{project_id}/api/v1/people/me.json` - the `id` node contains the id of the authorized user for project {project_id}.

for Basecamp3:

`https://3.basecampapi.com/{project_id}/my/profile.json` - the `id` node contains the id of the authorized user for project {project_id}.